# updating the child record and linking it to parent

Tags: apex, data-loader, relationships, upsert, externalid

I have scnerio where I am loading the child record from an external system and I want to connect it with the parent record. But I do not have the sfdc id
of the parent record that I can put in the lookup field.

On doing some research I found that we can use external id of the parent to connect both child and parent record but I am not clear how this relation can be established with the external id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The External Id needs to be on the record in Salesforce.

Say you have:

```
Account -> (Name = 'Example Account', External_Id__c = 'ABCD');
```

To link the Child Lookup using the External Id you would do:

```
Contact c = New Contact(LastName = 'Test', Account = New Account(External_Id__c = 'ABCD'));
upsert c;
```

**Note** For custom object you need to use the relationship so if the Lookup is `The_Parent__c` you would use `The_Parent__r = New The_Parent__c(External_Id__c = 'ABCD')`

**Note** The external Id operation requires you to use *upsert*.

If you simply want to update the Account itself:

```
Account a = New Account(External_Id__c = 'ABCD', Name = 'UpdatedName');
database.upsert(a, Account.External_Id__c);
```

or

```
upsert a External_Id__c
```

To upsert the record itself you would specify the external Id field and populate it

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57518/discussion-on-answer-by-eric-updating-the-child-record-and-linking-it-to-parent).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Data Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_import_wizard.htm&type=0) to match by External Id. Import the parents first, if necessary, then import the children.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57020/discussion-between-sfdcbat-and-sfdcfox).